# borg - Exclude a Folder with some Exceptions

Tags: borgbackup

Using borg [create](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html), I want to exclude a folder, but with some exceptions. Specifically, I want to exclude all paths subordinate to the AppData folder, except for the ones that are bookmark related, which would be paths that contain these strings:

1. places.sqlite
2. bookmarkbackups
3. Bookmarks

My thoughts were, first **exclude** what you don't want, and then **include** exceptions:

```
borg create --list --dry-run --exclude /*/AppData/* --include /*places.sqlite* --include /*bookmarkbackups* --include /*Bookmarks* /path/to/rep::$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') /windows/user/folder
```

Apparently, there is no `--include` argument. So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You are probably better off asking in the repo: https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/discussions
Anyways, probably constructing an appropriate regex would be sensible

Comment: Thank you. I posted my question here: https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/discussions/6123